# How to automatically update DOM or component when new item is added to database. I'm using React Hooks and axios

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-router, axios, react-hooks

----Home.js----

```
const Home=(props)=>
{
    const[posts,setPosts]=useState([])
    const [isLoaded,setLoad]=useState(false)
    useEffect(()=>{
        const getPosts = async ()=>{
            setLoad(true)
            const response =await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/posts')
                let post_list=response.data
                setPosts(post_list)
        }
        getPosts())}

    return(
        <div>
        {/* <h1>Welcome {userID}</h1> */}
        <div>
            {isLoaded?posts.map(post=>(
                <Post postObj={post} key={post._id}/>
            )):"Wall is loading"}
        </div>
        </div>
    )

----AddPost.js----

const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/addpost',postObj).catch(err=>console.log(err)).then(response=>{
        const resp=response.data.resp
        console.log(resp)
        setPost({
            img:'',
            tags:[],
            location:''
        })
        setTag('')
        setDonePost(true)
    })
}
```

---Post.js---

```
const DispTag=({tag})=>{
    return(
    <span>#{tag} </span>
    )
}

const Post=({postObj})=>{
    console.log(postObj)
return(
    <div>
    <div>
        {postObj['tags'].map(tag=><DispTag key={tag} tag={tag}/>)}
    </div>
    <img width="400" height="400" alt="" src={postObj.img}></img>
    </div>
) 
}
```

---App.js---

```
const App=()=>{
  return (
    <div>
     <Router>
    <Route path ='/home' render={()=><Home/>}/>
    <Route exact path='/' render={()=><AddPost/>}/>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried using useLayoutEffect,normal promises based axios requests but still I get error that i cant updated react state of unmounted component. How do i solve this without using react lifecycle methods

I've added all the files required. My issue is that nothing renders on Home after adding a new post(redirects to /home on submit) If i refresh or go directly to '/home' it displays all the posts as it should.

Answer (score 0):

change your home.js

```
const getPosts = async ()=>{
setLoad(true)
const response =await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/posts')
    let post_list=response.data
    setPosts(post_list)}

useEffect(()=>{
getPosts()},[])
```

and then add getPosts() after your handleSubmit() is done

Comment: handleSubmit() is done in other route though, what do you mean by add getPosts() after handleSubmit() is done.